# "const std::string &getStr" vs "std::string getStr"

Tags: c++

Can someone explain in simple words

why a developer did the following

```
const std::string &getStr() const
{
    return m_Str;
}
```

instead of

```
std::string getStr() const
{
    return m_Str;
}
```

Comment: Probably to speed it up by a few nanoseconds. People sometimes use the newly acquired knowledge just because they can. The developer recently discovered that classes can be passed by const reference, so they wanted to use this feature, and see if they like it or not.

Comment: one returns a copy the other returns a constant reference to the member. Thats quite different things

Comment: It's the default way of providing a non-modifying view over an object that may be expensive to copy. Strings in particular have a `std::string_view` alternative that's meant to be passed around by value.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica A `std::string` grants that its data is terminated by a `\0`. Taking a `std::string_view` of that `std::string`, this assumption gets lost. Hence, I consider returning a `std::string_view` instead of a `const std::string&` not as equivalent. (Sometimes, the terminating `\0` is required and would result in converting the `std::string_view` into a `std::string` by making a deep copy. There was a question concerning this and `std::filesystem::path` a while ago...)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat - That assumption is not lost, whomever is providing you the string_view can certainly provide that guarantee (at a documentation level too). There's more than just the standard's guarantees we can work with.

Comment: The different meaning should be explained in your C++ book, so what exactly is your question on top of the basic mechanisms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's two separate things. The second example returns a copy of the member variable `m_Str`, the first one a constant reference to the same variable. The difference is quite noticeable, if you take a look at the caller of this method. Imagine another method `setStr` that changes the member variable. Now take a look at the following code:

```cpp
instance.setStr("Foo");
const std::string& str = instance.getStr();
instance.setStr("Bar");
std::cout << str << std::endl; // Prints "Bar".
```

Whereas if you return a copy, the output will be different:

```cpp
instance.setStr("Foo");
std::string str = instance.getStr();
instance.setStr("Bar");
std::cout << str << std::endl; // Prints "Foo".
```

Comment: Another difference is that the reference to the string will be invalidated when `instance` is distroyed, whereas the copy of the string will remain valid.

Answer (score 1):

The second version will cause a copy of `m_Str` while the function returns, and that could unnecessarily reduce the performance each time calling the function. Returning a reference to const to it can easily solve this problem and eliminate redundant copy construct of temporary objects.

Yes, returning a const reference is not very common, if the function is just a normal non-member function, trying to returning a reference to it's local object would definitely cause a disaster, because the lifetime of the local object will end at the returning of the function. But a member function returning a member variable of `this` is a exception, the member variable is not a local object of the function, so returning it is all okay.

Comment: generally performance is important, but as the other answer explains the two methdods do something different, hence performance is kinda secondary. Both can be used to do the same thing to get a copy of the member, but then the argument about performance is moot

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number oh, I thought that the first version of the function will return a reference was already clear enough. isn't this question about why returning reference to const in getter for non-trivially copyable objects?